# Why isn't "der Bibliothek" in Dativ here?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

My professor asked us to formulate the phrase using this:

Ich - geben - zurück - sie (die Bücher) - Der Bibliothek

I wrote:

> Ich gebe sie dem Bibliothek zurück

But he shows the answer as

> Ich gebe sie der Bibliothek zurück

I don't understand why in this case, since I am returning something *to the* library, it shouldn't be in dativ case. Is it because of *zurück*? I am not entirely sure that the sentence makes sense to me.

Comment: Bibliothek ist weiblich. Wörterbucheintrag mit Tabelle: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bibliothek

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich "The noun Bibliothek is female. Therefore, the genitive is der Bibliothek". Why "genitive"? This question deals with dative.

Comment: Following our policy, you should always describe what you tried to answer the question yourself including what you do or don't understand. In this case, if you would have [looked up](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bibliothek) the Dativ of "Bibliothek", you would have found that Bibliothek is "feminin" and that the Dativ is indeed "der Bibliothek".

Comment: @Nico, my mistake. I thought it was asked for *Bücher der Bibliothek* (the books from the library).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I only remarked it in order for the asker not to get confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Answer is not wrong because of the case you used but because the library is a *feminine* word **Die Bibliothek**.

The dativ of **Die Bibliothek** is **Der Bibliothek**.